# Google app script error in FormApp.openById()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am getting an error in my code.gs at very line 3 of code -

```
// function to find the form id
function findFormIDs() {
  var form = FormApp.openById("my spreadsheet id");
}
```

error message is "Exception: Invalid ID (line 3, file "Code")"
I am confident that the spreadsheet ID I am passing is 100% correct. I have tried these creating new spreadsheets but getting the same error for each new spreadsheet.

Any debugging I can perform?

Comment: If you want to open a spreadsheet you would have to use SpreadsheetApp instead of FormApp. If you want to open the Form you would need the id of the form, not the spreadsheet.

Comment: For documentation reasons please accept the answer or provide your feedback in order to modify it and solve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to pass the correct type id to the respective class:

You should either call this to get a reference to the **spreadsheet**:

```
function findSpreadsheet() {
  var spreadsheet= SpreadsheetApp.openById("my spreadsheet id");
}
```

or this to get a reference to the **form**:

```
function findForm() {
  var form = FormApp.openById("my form id");
}
```